Interpretation of estimate in lme pairwise comparison
I am running this model: mod <- lme(log_weight ~ log_weight0 + Group*Day, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = mydata, na.action = na.exclude).
The Day variable is a factor in my model, so I can compare several groups at different days. For pairwise comparison I am using emmeans_results <- emmeans(mod, specs = trt.vs.ctrlk ~ Group | Day) and pairs(emmeans_results).
The output for example for Day=1 looks like:
 contrast                     estimate     SE  df  t.ratio  p.value
 Group1 - Group2              -0.026452 0.0423 202  -1.627  0.5817

My questions are: as my dependent variable is a log transformed weight, does the estimate mean log(weight of group1) - log(weight of group2) = log(weight of group1/weight of group2)? And as I know, if I transform it back it will be no longer the average of weight but rather the geometric mean of weights? So in my example the estimate -0.026 means that the geometric mean of weight of Group1 is lower by a factor of  exp(-0.026) than Group2?

If you add an argument to the emmeans() call:
EMM <- emmeans(mod, specs = trt.vs.ctrlk ~ Group | Day, tran = "log")

then you can handle this more explicitly. If you then do
summary(EMM, type = "response")

it will transform the EMMs to the original scale (and yes, they will be geometric means); and the contrast will be transformed to the ratio of those geometric means, since the difference of logs is the log of the ratio.
BTW, if you had fitted the model with the transformed response:
mod2 <- lme(log(weight) ~ log_weight0 + Group*Day, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = mydata, na.action = na.exclude)

then the log transformation will be auto-detected, and the tran argument is not needed.

Thank you, it helped a lot!
